# "Embedded" data.frame in R. What is it, what is it called, why does it behave the way it does?

Tags: r, dataframe, nested

I have the following data structure in R:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
    var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
    var2 = structure(
      list(
        var2a = c('v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'),
        var2b = c('vv', 'ww', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz')),
      .Names = c('var2a', 'var2b'),
      row.names = c(NA, 5L),
      class = 'data.frame'),
    var3 = c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee')),
  .Names = c('ID', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3'),
  row.names = c(NA, 5L),
  class = 'data.frame')

# Looks like this:
#   ID var1 var2.var2a var2.var2b var3
# 1  1    a          v         vv   aa
# 2  2    b          w         ww   bb
# 3  3    c          x         xx   cc
# 4  4    d          y         yy   dd
# 5  5    e          z         zz   ee
```

This looks like a normal data frame, and it behaves like that for the most part; but see `length` and `class` properties of the columns below:

```
class(df)
# [1] "data.frame"

df[1,]
# ID var1 var2.var2a var2.var2b var3
# 1     a          v         vv   aa

dim(df)
# [1] 5 4
# One less than expected due to embedded data frame

lapply(df, class)
# $ID
# [1] "integer"
# 
# $var1
# [1] "character"
# 
# $var2
# [1] "data.frame"
# 
# $var3
# [1] "character"

lapply(df, length)
# $ID
# [1] 5
#
# $var1
# [1] 5
#
# $var2
# [1] 2
#
# $var3
# [1] 5
# str(df)

# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  4 variables:
#   $ ID  : int  1 2 3 4 5
# $ var1: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
# $ var2:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ var2a: chr  "v" "w" "x" "y" ...
# ..$ var2b: chr  "vv" "ww" "xx" "yy" ...
# $ var3: chr  "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" ...
```

My questions:

## 1) What is this?

I've never come across this before. Is it a common format for some of you out there? What are potential use cases?

## 2) What is this called?

I called this "embedded" for lack of a better word. Somebody suggested "nested", but I don't think that's right, see separate section with `tidyverse` `tibble`s below.

## 3) Why is it allowed?

I would have expected the `structure` command above to fail, because I though that data.frames are essentially lists, where each element (column) has the same number of elements (rows). This rule seems violated in this example, as `var2` has `length = 2` (number of columns!). Yet, subsetting `df` surprisingly succeeds in the usual way:

```
df[3,]
#   ID var1 var2.var2a var2.var2b var3
# 3  3    c          x         xx   cc
```

What's going on?

---

I don't think I could call it a "nested" structure, that terminology is used for nested `data.frames` which would look and behave like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(
  x = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
  nested = list(data_frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c')), 
                data_frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c')), 
                data_frame(x = c('d', 'e', 'f'))))
unnest(df)
# # A tibble: 9 × 2
#       x     x
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1     a
# 2     1     b
# 3     1     c
# 4     2     a
# 5     2     b
# 6     2     c
# 7     3     d
# 8     3     e
# 9     3     f
```

Comment: A column of a `data.frame` can  be a `matrix`. Try for instance: `df$matcol<-matrix(1:15,ncol=3)`, which also breaks the rule of "same length columns" (you can see it with `lengths(df)`).

Comment: There's no official name for it. R data.frames DO NOT work well with embedded lists. Look at all the posts over the years caused by people trying to "embed" POSIXlt objects in dataframes. The consensus is clear .... DON'T.  If you need to use lists within lists then create a class name for it an provide the proper functionality, but do not call it a 'data.frame'.  Call it something else and make it S4. You should repair or flatten an abomination such as this rather than honoring it. Give MrFlick the points and move on to something useful.

Answer (score 4):

I think the strucutre makes it pretty clear

```
str(df)
# 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ ID  : int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ var1: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#  $ var2:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ var2a: chr  "v" "w" "x" "y" ...
#   ..$ var2b: chr  "vv" "ww" "xx" "yy" ...
#  $ var3: chr  "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" ...
```

It's a data.frame with a column (`var2`) that contains a data.frame. This isn't super easy to create so i'm not quite sure how you did it but it isn't technically "illegal" in R.

data.frames can contain matrices and other data.frames. So it doesn't just look at the `length()` of the elements, it looks at the `dim()` of the elements to see if it has the right number of "rows".

I often "fix" or expand these data.frames using

```
fixed <- do.call("data.frame", df)
```

Comment: Any thoughts on a name for this?

Comment: Other than "a bad idea"? Not really. I feel that if it doesn't work with `write.table` then it's not a "real" data.frame. The `data.frame()` constructor tries to avoid this, you it's usually created in some "unnatural" way.

Comment: I got it from a `JSON`, see my previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261430/embedded-data-frame-from-json

Comment: That's a side-effect of trying to automatically convert between incompatible data formats.  Data.frames expect nice, rectangular inputs like from CSV files. JSON can store crazy nested objects that don't have any column requirements. It's not too hard to come up with a JSON object that wouldn't make any sense as a data.frame. You should use `flatten=T` as recommended in the other answer.

Comment: Sadly you don't always get to choose your data sources. Plus, csv land is adjacent to excel hell ;) . My problem from the previous question is solved, this question is about better understanding this phenomenon of an embedded `data.frame`

Comment: More precisely it uses NROW(), rather than length(). See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#matrix-and-data-frame-columns for a little more info